# Adding delay to pulsed signal in matlab code with PWM block

Tags: digital-logic, pwm, pulse, matlab, simulink

How can I generate a pulsed (rectangular) signal such that, total period = 500ms (simulation time); clock frequency = 10kHz; pulse should occur every 20 ms. Duration of the pulse is the clock period and the pulse should shift with a phase shift of 2ms for 50 % of total simulation time and for the remaining 50% the phase shift should decrease by 2ms every pulse duration (ie. after each 20ms the pulse should shift by 1ms to the left i.e. decrease in a shift as compared to previous shift).

[image: Waveform should look something like this.]

The desired input is a MatLab code that can be fed into the main.c function block in Simulink. The output of this main.c block would be the compare value to be fed to the PWM block in Simulink.

Comment: Have you tried using simulink's built-in pulse generator? It allows us to set, time period, pulse width and other parameters for the pulse. You can use two such pulse generators; one for the left shifted pulses and one for the right shifted pulses. Use a time triggered switch to select one or the other. Alternately, I think what you want is a pulse position modulator. See if simulink has a readymade one available. Third option is to have a window comparator and feed it a modulating signal and a ramp wave form for generating pulse position modulation.

Comment: Would you still want to use matlab code if it can all be done with basic building blocks in simulink?

Comment: Yes, I need the code actually. I can do this using the Simulink blocks but actually, I am trying to replicate a microcontroller model in Matlab for a PWM application and the output of the PWM block should be this pulse (in the image). And the shifting operation is to be carried out by a function block containing the c code. So every time the interrupt signal of the uC is 1, the code will run and the corresponding shift in the pulse would occur.

Comment: Have written any code already ? Where exactly are you stuck ? If using simulink blocks, how will it look like ? Please add these details to your question using the [edit] button.

Comment: "*MatLab code that can be fed into the main.c*". Matlab code that can be fed to main. **c** ? Matlab code in a **C** language file ?